# BMI測定値のコーディングについて

Tags: java

入力した身長と体重からBMIを測定するプログラムを作成しています。
自分の身長と体重、BMIと標準体重を表示し、
3つ目のメソッドで返ってきた値がtrueであれば「合格！」、
falseであれば「頑張ろう！」と表示したいと思っていますが、
メソッドisHealthがうまく返せずいろいろ試してみるも、こんがらがってしまいました。

> boolean res = isHealth(re);

の箇所が「re を変数に解決できません」となってしまいます。
どなたかご教授いただけませんでしょうか。。

> 【コンソール画面サンプル】 
>   あなたの身長を入力
>   1.72 
>   あなたの体重
>    62
>   あなたの身長は1.72で
>   体重は62.0なので
>   BMIは20.9572....（省略
>   標準体重は65.0847.....（省略）
>   合格！！

```
package study;
import java.io.*;

public class bmi1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    BufferedReader a = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        double h, w, sta;
        try {
            System.out.println("あなたの身長(m)を入力してください");
            h = Double.parseDouble( a.readLine() );;
            System.out.println("あなたの体重(kg)を入力してください");
            w = Double.parseDouble( a.readLine() );

            double bmi = bmi(h,w);
            double stan = standard(h,sta);
            boolean res = isHealth(re);

            System.out.println("あなたの身長は"+h+"mで");
            System.out.println("あなたの体重は"+w+"kgなので");
            System.out.println("あなたのBMIは"+bmi);
            System.out.println("標準体重は"+sta+"なので");
            if(true){
                System.out.println("合格!!");
            }else{
                System.out.println("頑張ろう！");
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException o) {
            System.out.println("数字以外のものが入力されています");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
    private static double bmi(double h,double w){
        double bmi = w / ((h * h));
        //BMI＝体重（kg）÷（身長（m）×身長（m）
        return bmi;
    }
    private static double standard(double h,double w){
        double sta = h * h * 22;
        //標準体重（kg）＝身長（m）×身長（m）×22（BMI標準値）
        return sta;
    }
    private static boolean isHealth(double w, double sta){
        boolean result;
        //x標準体重(w)以下であればtrue、でなければfalseを返す
        result=(w < sta);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) `double stan = standard(h,sta);` (`sta`はこの時点で未設定というか呼び出した関数で使用されないので必要無い）--> `double stan = standard(h,w);` 2) `boolean res = isHealth(re);` 単なる注記間違いだと思われる。引数の数も異なる --> `boolean res = isHealth(w, stan);` 3) `if(true){` (`isHealth`の結果を使用するべき) --> `if(res){`

Comment: 似たような名前を付け過ぎた所為もあってさらに困惑してしまっていました。導いていただき、ありがとうございました！

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
boolean res = isHealth(re);
```

この行では `isHealth` という名前のメソッドに変数 `re` の値を渡し、返ってきた値を変数 `res` の初期値としています。しかしここには複数の問題があります。

- この行があるスコープでは、変数 `re` は宣言されていません（存在しません）。これがエラーメッセージ「re を変数に解決できません」が言っていることです。
- メソッド `isHealth` の定義を見ると、引数を2つ渡すようになっています。しかしこの行では引数を1つしか渡していません。

たとえば `isHealth(h, stan)` とするなどして、適切な引数を渡してあげてください。

Comment: ごちゃごちゃなコーディングであるにも関わらず、「原因」と「解説」をわかりやすく説明していただきありがとうございます！とても助かりました。